# Converting list of images to pdf in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, pdf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How can i convert list of images to pdf programmatically. In my current application, my requirement is i need to select some images from a list of images, and i need to import that images to pdf. Is there any open source project is available to implement this functionality. Can any one help me to find a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a control from ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PDFPhone/) that can do exactly what you want. Other than that, there are no public open-source components that I am aware of that would be 100% compatible with Windows Phone.

There is [SilverPDF](http://silverpdf.codeplex.com/) but it will require some fine tuning to get it working.