# Create PDF file with images in WinRT

Tags: pdf, windows-8, windows-runtime, pdf-generation

How I can create PDF files from a list of image in WinRT. I found something similar for windows phone 8 here("[Converting list of images to pdf in windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409203/converting-list-of-images-to-pdf-in-windows-phone-8)") But I am looking for a solution for windows 8. If anyone of having knowledge about this please share your thoughts with me.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://jspdf.com/

This should work on WinJS, but I haven't tested it. In a XAML app you can try to host a web browser control with a jsPDF-enabled page.

Answer (score 0):

[ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PDFWinRT/) has now released the same PDF library that they had in Windows Phone for Windows Runtime. Tho it's not open source, of course.

Answer (score 0):

[Amyuni PDF Creator for WinRT](http://w8pdf.com) (a commercial library) could be used for this task. You can create a new PDF file by creating a new instance of the class `AmyuniPDFCreator.IacDocument`, then add new pages with the method [AddPage](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_WinRT/AmyuniPDFCreator_IacDocument/Methods/IacDocument.AddPage_Method.htm), and add pictures to each page by using the method [IacPage.CreateObject](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_WinRT/AmyuniPDFCreator_IacPage/Methods/IacPage.CreateObject_Method.htm).

The code in C# for adding a picture to a page will look like this:

```cs
public IacDocument CreatePDFFromImage()
{
    IacDocument pdfDoc = new IacDocument();
    // Set the license key
    pdfDoc.SetLicenseKey("Amyuni Tech.", "07EFCD0...C4FB9CFD");
    IacPage targetPage = pdfDoc.GetPage(1); // A new document will always be created with an empty page

    // Adding a picture to the current page
    using (Stream imgStrm = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.OpenStreamForReadAsync("pdfcreatorwinrt.png"))
    {
        IacObject oPic = page.CreateObject(IacObjectType.acObjectTypePicture, "MyPngPicture");
        BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(imgStrm);
        byte[] imgData = binReader.ReadBytes((int)imgStrm.Length);
        // The "ImageFileData" attribute has not been added yet to the online documentation
        oPic.AttributeByName("ImageFileData").Value = imgData;
        oPic.Coordinates = new Rect(100, 2000, 1200, 2000);
    }
    return pdfDoc;
}
```

*Disclaimer: I currently work as a developer of the library*

For an "open source" alternative it might be better for you to [rely on a web service](http://www.silverlightrecipes.com/2012/03/consuming-soap-web-services-in-windows.html) that creates the PDF file using one of the many open source libraries available.

Answer (score -2):

I think this may help you if you want to convert an image (.jpg) file to a PDF file.
Its working in my lab.

```
string source = "image.jpg";
  string destinaton = "image.pdf";

  PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
  doc.Pages.Add(new PdfPage());
  XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]);
  XImage img = XImage.FromFile(source);
  xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
  doc.Save(destinaton);
  doc.Close();
```

Thanks.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Although it's not mentioned explicitly, this answer relies on the external library PDFSharp, which is not compatible with Windows Store (WinRT) applications.