# Windows 8 phone app image to PDF conversion

Tags: image

I have just started creating windows phone 8 app. I want to covert image (.jpg) file to PDF file. But I have no idea how to do it.

I have searched on the net but found the solution for Windows store app (Windows 8 Desktop) not for Windows 8 phone app.

Please help me.

Comment: Is your application online of offline? Because, if your app work with internet, you can create Conver2Pdfservice based for e.g on `Windows Azure`, which returned for you pdf file. In the other hand perhaps this link helps [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409203/converting-list-of-images-to-pdf-in-windows-phone-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409203/converting-list-of-images-to-pdf-in-windows-phone-8)

Comment: My application is offline. So I need a way to save the .jpg image file in to PDF file. I know we can do it easily for Windows 8 Desktop using  string source = (e.Argument as string[])[0];
string destinaton = (e.Argument as string[])[1];
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
doc.Pages.Add(new PdfPage());
XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]);
XImage img = XImage.FromFile(source);
xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
doc.Save(destinaton); But PDFDocument class is not available for windows 8